# is this java interface tactic sound?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I've been thinking about implementing a certain tactic for my code.

This is my setup:

I've got an interface called "Object".
Then I've got an interface called "Entity" that extends "Object".
From entity then springs countless implementations, like "army", "city", "lemon", etc.

Now, I want to gather all of these Objects into some form of map. Then from that map I want to get the particular implementation of "Object".

My thought out solution for this is as follows:

Object has method :

```
public Entity getEntity()
```

All implementations of Object returns null, while Entity returns itself.

Likewise, in entity I'd have:

```
public Army getArmy()
public City getCity()
```

That way, I can simply pull an object from the map and get the specific class from it with a series of null checks, like so;

```
Object o = Objects.getObject(2dCoordinates);
Entity e = o.getEntity();
if (e != null){
Army a = e.getArmy();
if (a != null)
a.armySpecificMethod();
}
```

All without using "instanceof" and casting, which I hate.

The question is whether there's some unforeseen problem about this? I'd rather learn from someone that knows before refactoring my code and find out for myself.

Comment: Read about `instanceof`

Comment: First, you can't have an interface called Object. Object is already a class name in java. Second, are there any objects that implement "Object" but no "Entity"

Comment: Yes, there will be plain object implementations. And I'm aware of the name conflict.

Comment: @DJClayworth you can (but should not) create your own `Object` actually by using fully-qualified name.

Comment: That looks like a job for the visitor pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example

Comment: It seems you would only trade `instanceof` for a null check. Note that with Java 8 you can provide default implementation for, let's say, `getArmy()` to return null and override it in only in the `Army` class.

Comment: And Dmirty, I don't see how reading up on instanceof would help me? Is there something in my text that implies that I don't know about it?

Comment: yshavit: It will return null

Comment: Just read that, sorry, missed it the first time. In that case, I fully agree with @kajacx. You're doing an instance-of check without using the `instanceof` keyword; that's not really an improvement. I think if you stopped and asked yourself _why_ you hate `instanceof`, you'd find that most if not all of those reasons apply to this pattern as well.

Comment: kajacx: The benefit as I see it is that I don't have to do any casting.

Comment: What specifically do you not like about casting?

Comment: @Jake what you are doing here is throwing away tools which Java provides you and writing your own RTTI, which is just longer way of writing `instanceof` and doing cast. `instanceof` + cast is perfectly safe operation.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to bow out of this discussion, because the comments thread is not a place to have extended discussion. I'd take it to the chat room, but I need to get back to work. :) But again, I would encourage you to focus not on _what_ you don't like, but _why_ you don't like it, and make sure that whatever you come up with is an actual improvement.

Comment: I was convinced that casting would give me some supress warning, but now that I try it out, I see that that isn't the case. Silly me. Well I got my answer. The only negative I still see about instanceof + casting is that a client wouldn't know what to compare with or cast to...

Comment: Just a small note: in APIs that use similar strategies, these methods are called `asXXX()` and not `getXXX()`. It is more readable and keeps getters clean. But I'd probably choose a different strategy altogether, like the Visitor pattern.

Comment: biziclop: So, there are APIs that use this method? Do they return null, as in my example?

Comment: @Jake No, they throw a `ClassCastException`. Here's an [example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/xml/stream/events/XMLEvent.java#XMLEvent.asStartElement%28%29).

Comment: And note that those classes have an `isXXX` for each `asXXX`. So the pattern is first you ask "is this a Foo", and then you get it as a  Foo. Again, a cast by any other name. :)

Comment: @yshavit Indeed, they're pure convenience methods that add nothing over instanceof + cast, only improve readability. So much so that in the example I linked to, only the 3 most frequently used subclasses have such a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked if there are any pitfalls to your strategy. I would say no, since C# uses the same strategy with their [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword. Example: `e as Army` would return `e` if `e` is-a `Army`, or `null` otherwise. It is basicly a cast that instead of failing returns `null`.

However you don't have to implement this functionality using interfaces, you can write your own `as` method for example like this:

```
static <T> T as(Class<T> clazz, Object obj) {
    if (clazz.isInstance(obj)) {
        return (T) obj;
    }
    return null;
}
```

usage:

```
Object o = Objects.getObject(2dCoordinates);
Entity e = as(Entity.class, o);
if (e != null) {
    Army a = as(Army.class, e);
    if (a != null)
    a.armySpecificMethod();
}
```

Comment: There is one pitfall though: it's not idiomatic in Java. And of course if you want to make sure you've covered every possible subclass, this is not the way to do it either.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to register callbacks/strategies to be invoked on particular events. Something like that:

```
public interface OnMapClicked<T> {

    void onItemSelected(T item);

}
```

And your GameMap (or whatever) implementation would be:

```
public GameMap {

    private final Map<Class<?>, OnMapClicked> listeners = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void registerListener(Class<? extends T> type, OnMapClicked<T> listener) {
         listeners.put(type, listener);
    }

    //

    private void onMapClicked(Coordinates coordinates) {
        Object object = findObject(coordinates);

        listeners.get(object.getClass()).onItemSelected(object);
    }

}
```

That's very rough untested implementation, but hopefully you got the idea. There is one usage of non-generic instance here (in onMapClicked), but it should be safe, since we're checking the input type in `registerListener`.